# Spaces between UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableViewController` that is segue-embedded to an `UIContainerView` and I need to appropriate some spacing between the **static** `UITableViewCells` that are in the view.

Here's my `UITableViewController`:

[image]

What is the fastest and easiest way to add a space above the very first cell(The top cell borders with the navigation bar at run time.. no space) and a space between the second and third `UITableViewCell`?  I am pretty sure I need to use `cellHeightForRowAtIndexPath:` but I have no idea how to call out each cell or how to appropriately add spaces in the right places.

Comment: Are these static cells from a storyboard?

Comment: Change their height in the storyboard! Each cell can have its own custom defined height.

Comment: yeah just add a cell that doesn't contain anything but is a different color.

Comment: If it is static you can Add a cell,add height how much you needed